# TranslateAnimation move view off screen -Android

Tags: android

I'm using the following animation on a GridView,

I hide it when the activity loads up with slideToBottom(myGridView);

```
public void slideToBottom(View view){
    TranslateAnimation animate = new TranslateAnimation(0,0,0,view.getHeight());
    animate.setDuration(500);
    animate.setFillAfter(true);
    view.startAnimation(animate);
    view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

The problem I'm having is that when click a botton to show the view it just makes it visible with no animation, when I click it again it loads the animation, the code to slide it to top is below,

```
public void slideToTop(View view){
    TranslateAnimation animate = new TranslateAnimation(0,0,view.getHeight(),0);
    animate.setDuration(1000);
    animate.setFillAfter(true);
    view.startAnimation(animate);
    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}


<RelativeLayout

    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    >
    ....some other stuff here

    <GridView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/myGridView"
        android:horizontalSpacing="2dip"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:verticalSpacing="0dip"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
         />


</RelativeLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this relates to the issue, but in your code:

```
view.startAnimation(animate);
view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

`startAnimation()` only starts the animation. You should wait for it to finish before setting visibility to GONE;

See the example at [Hide view with animation and set visibility to gone without flash the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17465860/hide-view-with-animation-and-set-visibility-to-gone-without-flash-the-screen)

Similarly, to slide in the view, you should make it visible before beginning animation.